# Query about meaning of sed expression

Tags: sed

I am starting with `bash` and I had this expression line. I am lost figuring what it means.

I know from the manual the meaning of `sed` and its option `-n` but I don't get the meaning of the last part:

```
sed -n "n;p"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`n` skips processing the current line and reads the next. More correctly, the command replaces sed's current work buffer (correct term "pattern space") with the next line. `p` prints it.

Since `-n` suppresses implicit printing, the result is that every other line is printed.

See also the [sed manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#sed-commands-list).

Answer (score 0):

This does not have anything to do with the `bash` shell other than that you happen to be using it to execute `sed`.

The `n` editing command in `sed` outputs the current buffer unless the default output has been turned off with `-n` (as it has been in the example command that you show), and it then causes the next line to be read into the buffer.

The `p` editing command outputs the current buffer, regardless of whether `-n` has been used or not.

The effect is that every second line, starting with the first line of input, is discarded, and the others are printed.

The effect is the same as with `sed -n '2~2p'` or `sed '2~2!d'` or `sed '1~2d'` when using GNU `sed`.  This `2~2` means "every second line from the second line on-wards" and `1~2` means "every second line from the first line on-wards".  The `~` address range modifier is a GNU `sed` extension.

With `awk`, you'd get the same effect with `awk '(FNR % 2) == 0'` where `FNR` by default is the line number of the current input file and `%` is the common modulus operator.